# How to run external Javascript file plugin in ReactJS using lifecycle

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, reactjs

I'm setting up animation plugin using external Javascript file to create Globe Tag Cloud. I've been tested on normal html it's run well, but when I call on ReactJS it's always give me error message like this:

> TypeError:
>   jquery__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_6___default(...)(...).SVG3DTagCloud is
>   not a function

I'm using lifecycle method, like this, it's success inject JS file to HTML body but still not working and give me error message.

```
componentDidMount() {
    var cloudTag = document.createElement('script');

    cloudTag.src = '/svg3dtagcloud.min.js';
    cloudTag.async = true;

    $(document).ready(function () {
      // This is was on the documentation https://github.com/NiklasKnaack/jquery-svg3dtagcloud-plugin
      var entries = [
        {label: 'Tag One', url: '#', target: '_top'},
        {label: 'Tag Two', url: '#', target: '_top'},
        {label: 'Tag Three', url: '#', target: '_top'},
        {label: 'Tag Four', url: '#', target: '_top'},
        {label: 'Tag Five', url: '#', target: '_top'}
      ];

      var settings = {
          entries: entries,
          width: 480,
          height: 480,
          radius: '65%',
          radiusMin: 75,
          bgDraw: true,
          bgColor: '#111',
          opacityOver: 1.00,
          opacityOut: 0.05,
          opacitySpeed: 6,
          fov: 800,
          speed: 1,
          fontFamily: 'Oswald, Arial, sans-serif',
          fontSize: '15',
          fontColor: '#fff',
          fontWeight: 'normal',
          fontStyle: 'normal',
          fontStretch: 'normal',
          fontToUpperCase: true,
          tooltipFontFamily: 'Oswald, Arial, sans-serif',
          tooltipFontSize: '11',
          tooltipFontColor: '#fff',
          tooltipFontWeight: 'normal',
          tooltipFontStyle: 'normal', 
          tooltipFontStretch: 'normal',
          tooltipFontToUpperCase: false,
          tooltipTextAnchor: 'left',
          tooltipDiffX: 0,
          tooltipDiffY: 10
      };

      cloudTag.onload = () => {
        $('#holder').SVG3DTagCloud(settings);
      }
    });

    document.body.appendChild(cloudTag);
}
```

How to run external Javascript plugins file to run on ReactJS properly? Is any method to run the function inside?

Comment: add this inside componentDidMount if(!jQuery().SVG3DTagCloud) {
    $.fn.SVG3DTagCloud=function(){}
 }

Comment: @Sujit.Warrier he did it, you can see from the code

Comment: sorry the comment got submitted incomplete. have edited it

Comment: The idea is bad - you can't be sure the library will stop loading after you pin source code inside script tag, because init function of library can be async. Best way is import it from npm if possible (github packages you can load as well) or load all CDN libraries at the beginning and create splashscreen. Since you have to wait at the library you can also set async to false;

Comment: @Sujit.Warrier thank you, error message is gone, but still doesn't return anything

Comment: Error is gone because it's not using this library if it's not loaded, but this is not solution.

Comment: the error message is gone because I have temporarily defined the function, but for it to start working you need to ensure the library is loaded. maybe in the App.js you can wait for the JS library to be loaded before calling the ReactDOM.render

Comment: I had a similar problem when we had to use a librarhy for which no npm package was available, in app.js I ensured download of library and on completion I called ReactDom.Render

Answer (score 0):

If you can, you shouldn't load libraries like this, unless yoiu can do it in reactive way. What you do in this code, you try to create async side-effect in component. For async actions inside component you should try some middleware. Eg. https://github.com/redux-observable/redux-observable if you're using redux for global state or https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux-thunk. But for performance reasons I would simply download this library at the beginnging and even cache it with web wroker, there is no big gain loading it only when component mounts.

Comment: I'm trying to false async, and still not return anything.

Comment: @Dexter async false can be set by the way to know the order of loaded libraries - just in html add this library in an old way. You can also try download library as content type text and set content of cloudTag.innerText to the downloaded code - so you can know more precise when code is beeing executed. But downloading is acync as I said, so either use .then or await syntax, or middleware.